Disable `audio` html tag
I have an html audio tag in my project, which in some situation I need to disable.
In order to do it I apply the following css by adding disabled class to the audio tag:
audio.disabled {
  pointer-events: none
}

I would like to add a layer with opacity 50% that will cover the audio element, in order to give a different view for it when it is disabled.
I thought to use the pseudo class ::before, but do not manage to have a visible element.
Here is a snippet with what I have already:


function toggleAudioDisable() {
  document.getElementById('myAudio').classList.toggle("disabled");
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none
}
<audio id="myAudio" controls="controls" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg"></audio> <br> 

<button onclick="toggleAudioDisable()">Toggle Audio Disable</button>



Any idea how to implement it?

Why don't you simply apply the style opacity: 0.5 to the disabled audio element? In Chrome this works like a charm.

@JSONDerulo, very interesting, it seems that the simplest solution has escaped me.... However, I don't know if it will work on all browsers, but thanks anyway!

I added a layer with opacity: 0.5 and it will works as you want. Hope it helps you!


function toggleAudioDisable() {
  const audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
  const isDisabled = audio.classList.toggle("disabled");

  const blocker = document.getElementById('blocker');
  if (isDisabled) {
    blocker.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    blocker.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
.audio-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

audio.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.blocker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #FFF;
}
<div class="audio-wrapper">
    <audio id="myAudio" controls src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg"></audio>
    <div id="blocker" class="blocker"></div>
</div>
<br> 
<button onclick="toggleAudioDisable()">Toggle Audio Disable</button>




I second jerad.blair's answer, but if you were wondering why it isn't working your way (or need to specify other properties in the future like background-color or content), it is because <audio> acts like a "replaced element". This means the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements will not be displayed if the element loads/renders properly. Read more on the MDN Web Docs
The solution using a ::before element would require you to layer a non-replaced element in the markup, such as a <div>. So something like this will work:
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <audio id="myAudio" controls="controls" src="..."></audio>
  </div>
  <br />
  <button onclick="toggleAudioDisable()">Toggle Audio Disable</button>
</body>
<script>
  function toggleAudioDisable() {
    document.getElementById("myAudio").classList.toggle("disabled");
  }
</script>
<style>
  div:has(#myAudio) {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }
  div:has(.disabled) {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  div:has(.disabled)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: white; /* alternatively, use your container background color */
  }
</style>
</html>

This is quite a lot of markup and style overhead for simply an extra opacity property, but if you need to do anything more complex with the pseudo-element (e.g., background-color, content), you may have to go this route.

"I would like to add a layer with opacity 50% that will cover the audio element, in order to give a different view for it when it is disabled."
You can do this by adding an 'opacity' declaration to your .disabled class.


function toggleAudioDisable() {
  document.getElementById('myAudio').classList.toggle("disabled");
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 50%;
}
<audio id="myAudio" controls="controls" src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg"></audio> <br> 

<button onclick="toggleAudioDisable()">Toggle Audio Disable</button>




Use disabled attribute to prevent user interaction with  element.
Updated toggleAudioDisable function:
function toggleAudioDisable() {
  var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
  if(audio.hasAttribute('disabled')){
    audio.removeAttribute('disabled');
    audio.classList.remove('disabled');
  } else {
    audio.setAttribute('disabled', disabled);
    audio.classList.add('disabled');
  }
}

Updated style:
audio.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


Why don't you style the tag itself "audio"?
Audio elements have the following pseudo-element selectors in CSS:
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button

If this option does not suit you, I recommend creating a div container where you can add .audio-container::before
<div class="audio-container">
   <audio>
</div>

